# Looping through a spreadsheet and plotting all columns with xlsxwriter, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, xlsxwriter

I bet I'm really close here.  I'm trying to look at spreadsheets with potentially 100's of columns and create a plot in a new spreadsheet for each column on the fly.  I've got a few of these working where I simply call multiple calls to chart1,chart2,chart3......

What I have below loops fine, inserts the data in the first sheet, creates the second sheet and inserts only the first chart.  How do I write the loop to create "n" charts?

I bet it's a silly trivial thing.

Thanks in advance.

Input Data:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sts5axnT7aQ04zHv8nPwhnrQPDb7oZlV

```
import pandas as pd
import codecs
import csv
import os
import xlsxwriter
import datetime
df3 = pd.read_csv('TEST.csv', index_col=0, header=[0], low_memory=False, na_filter=True, encoding='utf-8')
writer2 = pd.ExcelWriter('TEST.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
#define the sheetname
stage = 10
sheetname1 = "Stage_" +str(stage)
print(sheetname1)
df3.to_excel(writer2, sheet_name = sheetname1 , startrow=4, startcol=0, encoding='utf8')
maxcol = df3.shape[1]-1
maxlen = df3.shape[0]-1
print(maxcol, maxlen)
#set the workbook value
c = df3[['TWO']]
workbook = writer2.book
#set the worksheet value
sheetname2 = "Stage_" +str(stage) +str("_P")
c.to_excel(writer2, sheet_name = sheetname2 , startrow=4, startcol=0, encoding='utf8')
print(sheetname2)
worksheet = writer2.sheets[ sheetname2 ]
for i in range(2, maxcol):
    TITLE = df3.columns[i]
    LOC_NUM = (i - 1) * 34 - 33
    LOCATION = "C" +str(LOC_NUM)
    print("TITLE:", TITLE, "GRAPH_LOCATION:", LOC_NUM,LOCATION, "LENGTH:", maxlen, "INDICE:", i)
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
    chart.set_size({'width': 1200, 'height': 640})
    chart.add_series({"values" : [ sheetname1 , 7, i ,maxlen, i ],"name" : TITLE })
    chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Time (s)', 'position_axis': 'on_tick'})
    chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Test', 'major_gridlines': {'visible': False}})
    # Turn off chart legend. It is on by default in Excel.
    chart.set_legend({'position': 'none'})
    worksheet.insert_chart( LOCATION , chart )
    writer2.save()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What *is* your question? Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How do i create the loop so that I can get a chart for each column?